# Decrypt in Android values Encrypted with .NET AesCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I have values stored in a database that were encrypted with .NET AesCryptoServiceProvider. I need to decrypt these values in Android. I found the CryptLib class and am able to encrypt/decrypt using that class, but I'm getting different results than what I got with the AesCryptoServiceProvider. I'm using the same Key and IV values and no salting, so I don't understand what else to look for. I appreciate it if anybody might point me in the right direction.

For testing I'm just trying to Encrypt the same value again and see if I get the same results. In the CryptLib function

```
public String encryptPlainText(String plainText, String key, String iv) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = encryptDecrypt(plainText, CryptLib.SHA256(key, 32), EncryptMode.ENCRYPT, iv);
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I've tried replacing CryptLib.SHA256(key, 32) with just key. This just provides yet another result; neither method matches the result from .NET.

Here is how I'm calling the CryptLib class:

```
            CryptLib cryptLib = new CryptLib();
            String encryptedString = cryptLib.encryptPlainText(plainText, key, iv);
```

This is a portion of the CryptLib class:

```
private byte[] encryptDecrypt(String inputText, String encryptionKey,
                                  EncryptMode mode, String initVector) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        int len = encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length; // length of the key  provided

        if (encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length > _key.length)
            len = _key.length;

        int ivlength = initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length;

        if(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length > _iv.length)
            ivlength = _iv.length;

        System.arraycopy(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, _key, 0, len);
        System.arraycopy(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, _iv, 0, ivlength);


        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(_key, "AES"); // Create a new SecretKeySpec for the specified key data and algorithm name.

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(_iv); // Create a new IvParameterSpec instance with the bytes from the specified buffer iv used as initialization vector.

        // encryption
        if (mode.equals(EncryptMode.ENCRYPT)) {
            // Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older. Read for more info.
            // https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html
            _cx.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this cipher instance
            return _cx.doFinal(inputText.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Finish multi-part transformation (encryption)
        } else {
            _cx.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this cipher instance

            byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decode(inputText.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            return _cx.doFinal(decodedValue); // Finish multi-part transformation (decryption)
        }
    }
```

.NET:

```cs
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText,  byte [] myaesiv) //, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
           byte [] aesbyte = Convert.FromBase64String(aeskey);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aesbyte, myaesiv);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {


                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        sw.Write(plainText);
                    encrypted = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        String s = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
        return s; 
    }
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for this CryptLib class?

Comment: https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/blob/master/Android/CryptLib.java

Comment: Your C# is base64 decoding some mystery variable. Your Java is SHA256ing something. If the input strings are the same the outputs are not... (also: use a better KDF).